# The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, assembly-references

I have the following problem with a referenced assembly from a Web application:

Web application assembly/namespace:

> Company.Application.Web

Referenced assembly:

> Company.Application.Infrastructure including namespaces
>   Company.Application.Infrastructure.Data
>   Company.Application.Infrastructure.Services

In the following code I get an error message at the `using` statements in a Web application file:

> The type or namespace name 'Infrastructure' does not exist in the namespace 'Company.Application' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

```
using Company.Application.Infrastructure.Data
using Company.Application.Infrastructure.Services

namespace Company.Application.Web
{

}
```

Comment: Um. We won't be able to help you solve this without seeing the relevant code. Visual Studio isn't [cray cray](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cray-cray); you're missing something.

Comment: Actually, I have shown all relevant code. When I comment all code except for the namespace and the usings, the same errors occur.

Comment: I've edited your question to contain the code (as it should look); also, you're going to have to include screenshots of the actual assembly references in the project or you're going to have to give us the actual CSProj XML and its appropriate references for us to help you. As it stands, all I can say is, "You messed up somewhere" because I don't have enough information to tell you where you messed up.

Comment: What about that `<br>` after the `Company.Application.Web` namespace - is that intentional?

Comment: Check .Net Framework Target, if your Company.Application.Infrastructure is built for higher .NET Framework Version then MSBuild/VS may not recognize it.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - just an artifact from how they originally posted their code (using HTML markup) and the subsequent cleanup to use proper code markup

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
....

Comment: <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Company.Application.Core\Company.Application.Core.csproj">
      <Project>{3F9B672A-A982-47C5-B632-45BC16B7DBF0}</Project>
      <Name>Company.Application.Core</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Company.Application.Infrastructure\Company.Application.Infrastructure.csproj">
      <Project>{D13B1CE1-5B91-4CAA-9408-B97B0F8C4EA9}</Project>
      <Name>Company.Application.Infrastructure</Name>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>False</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: @Akash Both projects use .NET Framework 4.0 (not client profile). I have no problems in a Test project using the same references.

Comment: I changed the underlying VSS project structure, restored the broken references and after that the problem was magically solved. Thanks everyone for the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see that your target framework have the same .net versions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The .NET versions are the same as far as I can see.